# How to set Struts 2 object inside a Struts 2 tag (a href)

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

I have File object which looks like this

```
public class FileTO implements Serializable{
private String fileName;
private String filePath;

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}

public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public String getFilePath() {
    return filePath;
}

public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
    this.filePath = filePath;
}
```

Of course there are lot other objects in my struts action response, which I am not listing here.
After the action completes, the filePath will be populated with the actual path of the file where it resides so that the file can be downloaded. I want to display the fileName and filePath in a `<s:a>` tag.

Goal is to have href point to filePath. I tried play with OGNL i.e #, %{}, $() and none seems to display the link properly.

Eg:

```xml
<s:a href="?????????"> Click to the get the File </s:a>
```

Comment: can u provide ur action class code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear but from what I understand, you're looking for `s:url` tag.

```xml
<a href="<s:url value="%{filePath+fileName}"/>">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```xml
> <s:a href="?????????"> Click to the get the File </s:a>
> ```

1. If the file is in an accessible folder:

   ```xml
   <s:a href="http://server.with.files.com/path/to/file/fileName.txt"> 
       Click to the get the File 
   </s:a>
   ```
2. If the file is in a folder that is protected, not accessible, or is inside the webapplication, or comes from a database, etc... you should call an Action (or a Servlet, if not in Struts2), that should read the file, and return a Stream result. Read:

   - [How to use Stream result from Action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16935198/1654265)
   - [How to download a file from Action / Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16900840/1654265)

To understand the OGNL syntax, instead, [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620838/1654265).