# Struts 2.0 download file from Server

Tags: java, struts2, download, client-side

I have create download method to download file from server-side to client-side, but I had this error appear, the file is successfully downloaded to client-side tough, but I have this error so I can't return to previous page properly.

This is my error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.decorator.BaseWebAppDecorator.render(BaseWebAppDecorator.java:39)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at gnv.carnaval.webapp.filter.LocaleFilter.doFilterInternal(LocaleFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And this is my download method:

```
private void downloadReceipt(String path, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(path);
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
        response.reset();
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
        //copy binary contect to output stream
        while(fileIn.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1)
        {
            out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
        }

        fileIn.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do not close `out.close()` just flush it and try to keep closing of streams in `finally ` block..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reinventing the wheel (squared). The exception is thrown because you are writing twice to the OutputStream (one time manually, then another writing is performed by the framework).

To download a file in Struts2, you should use `Stream` result [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16935198/1654265), eventually pointing to a new window / tab, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16900840/1654265).

There are cases where you still might want to write manually to the OutpuStream, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16654313/1654265), but in those **edge** cases, you need to return `Action.NONE` (that will prevent the framework from writing to the OutputStream) to avoid getting the exception you are getting now.

Comment: i think i want to write manually to the OutputStream , but in your example still calling ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream(); , isnt that what makes error occurred?

Comment: No, the error occours when you call `return SUCCESS;` (or any other result different from `NONE`) because the framework will write the result to the OutputStream. BTW why do you think you want to manually write it ? Have you tried the way the framework provide you with the Stream result ?

Comment: Waw @Andrea that's true, im not getting an error if i return NONE , and now, how can i some kind of refresh the page right after that? is that possible?

Comment: Please, read the answer AND the answers linked in it, try then feed me back ;) all you need is there. You can't download a file and refresh the page. Refresh with what BTW ? The number of times the file has been downloaded ? A message saying "downloaded successfull ?" Those would be other questions and should be asked as different question here on SO... please try this, once completed succesfull remember to accept the answer and target the new problem

Answer (score 0):

To service a request, you can either use the PrintWriter or the OutputStream, not both

At some point after your processing, the framework is trying to get a handle to the PrintWriter object of the response (using response.getWriter()).

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
>       at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.decorator.BaseWebAppDecorator.render(BaseWebAppDecorator.java:39)

This will throw the exception you are seeing because you have already called the response.getOutputStream() to write back your file.

Comment: Ok @ramp i get the error, so i have to change my download method right? I try several others, but all of them require me to do 'response.getOutputStream()'. Is there any other possible download method that i can use ?

Comment: No. You have done right. You need the output stream to write back the file. You should have some way, within the framework you use, to instruct it not to do any 'rendering'. Because a download by itself is a **completed** response. You cannot both 'download' a file and 'render' a response in the same request. Your response header speaks for itself. It should either be an attachment or 'text/html' - you cannot have both.